# How to get history for all the pages of SVN

Tags: java, eclipse, svn

I am checking out my entire code from SVN a server and export it into eclipse. If I do history check for a page (by going Right click -> Team -> Show History), it will show me history from all user for that page.

I want history for all pages. I cant do it one by one as there is huge number of pages.
Is there is any shortcut to do it?

Comment: Page? Don't you mean files?

Answer (score 3):

Show history for the root (i.e. your project) of whatever is version controlled. This should give you all changes.

Answer (score 0):

I guess with page you mean file. You can show history of the root of your project. If you want to see the whole history of one file, go Window-Preference-Team-SVN-Default number of log messages. raise that to a higher number...